# Repeating text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to create new excel files regularly with "address" in one of the columns.
Is there any way by which I can easily enter address with just writing 2 or 3 initials.

There are 2 columns date & address. I have to create this file containing product dispatched daily to following address. Content in address column usually remains constant but corresponding date changes. I have to create a different file for every month. Is there any trick to ease work of typing address every time?

```
   date               address
01-01-2016     green wood, new york
02-01-2016     heaven world, texas
03-01-2016     time square, california
```

Comment: Please STOP SHOUTING and/or buy a new keyboard that allows you to type lower case letters.

Comment: Yes you can. Just write 2 or 3 initials in the cell to represent the address since it remains constant as you say. Example HW for heaven world.

Comment: You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a sample that you can adapt to your specific layout.  Say our data is like:

[image]

The first step is to create an **abbreviation table**, *(here columns E and F)*

[image]

You can use any abbreviations you like, just don't duplicate them.

Then enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rB As Range, rTab As Range
   Dim v As String, rGrab As Range
   Set rB = Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count)
   Set rTab = Range("E:E")

   If Intersect(rB, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   v = Target.Text
   Set rGrab = rTab.Find(What:=v, After:=rTab(1), LookAt:=xlWhole)
   If rGrab Is Nothing Then
      Exit Sub
   Else
      Application.EnableEvents = False
         Target.Value = rGrab.Offset(0, 1).Value
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Now if we type the abbreviation in column **B** and touch the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the full address will be substituted. The code and abbreviation table should be inserted in each worksheet you wish to process.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**